# Using arrays to get positive numbers

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, return

I'm trying to return the positive numbers in an array. I'm new to arrays and am having trouble figuring it out.

```
public class PossitiveArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] numbers = {2,-1,5,-4,3};
     System.out.print(numbers);

    }
    public static int[] getPositiveNumbers(int[] numbers)
    {

        for (int n : numbers)
        {
            if(n>0)
            {
                int [] nums = numbers;
            }
        }

        return nums;

    }
}
```

Analysis-
This is what I came up with. As it is right now it gives me and error saying I need to make a local variable for nums but when I do that it returns "[I@677327b6". I tried to make it return numbers but i'm not sure what to put into the if statement.

Required-
The goal is to just have positive numbers returned. Any help would be appreciate I am very knew to arrays and programing in general.

Comment: The line `int[] nums = numbers;` doesn't make any sense given what you want to do. it simply copies the entire array. A better approach would be to create a local `ArrayList<int>` and add the numbers you want into that (in the `for` loop). And if you really need to return it as an array call its `toArray` method before returning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below Code-

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] numbers = {2,-1,5,-4,3};
     for(int n : getPositiveNumbers(numbers)){
         System.out.print(n);    
     }


    }
    public static int[] getPositiveNumbers(int[] numbers)
{
    int count = 0;
     for (int n : numbers)
     {
         if(n>0)
         {
            count++;
         }
     }
    int [] nums = new int[count];
    int i =0;
    for (int n : numbers)
    {
        if(n>0)
        {
           nums[i] = n;
           i++;
        }
    }

    return nums;

}
}
```

Comment: What about all the trailing zeros in the array?

Comment: Actually this is because of the size of the array declared. If you declare the array size equal to positive numbers in array, then there will no trailing zeros.

Comment: Yes this works but how do I get rid of the zeros in place of the negative numbers.

Comment: How do you do that @kushagramittal

Answer (score 3):

Java 8's streams would make this take much easier:

```
public static int[] getPositiveNumbers(int[] numbers) {
    return Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(i -> i > 0).toArray();
}
```

Regarding printing the result - you're seeing the default `toString()`, as `int[]` does not override it. Instead, you could use [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) to print the result.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider here to answer your question.

1. Variable scope of nums is local to the loop. This means that `nums` will be deleted each time the for-loop iterates, and will be gone when the loop ends. You can address this by moving the declaration to before the for-loop.
2. Your declaration `int[] nums` only declares that nums is an array of ints, but doesn't allocate any space to put anything into the array. You must allocate the space using for example `int[] nums = new int[5]`, which creates an array of 5 slots. In your case, you'll want an array that will hold all the positive numbers, which at most will be the entirety of the input array. Use `int [] nums = new int[numbers.length]` to accomplish this (but see next point).
3. How do you want to fill the new array nums containing only the positive integers? The way you have it written it looks like you would like `{2,-1,5,-4,3}` to return `{2, 5, 3}`, or would you rather it return `{2,0,5,0,3}`. Either case will affect how your for-loop should handle nums. For an output of `{2, 5, 3}` the size of the array needs to figured out beforehand by counting the number of positive entries first.

NOTE: This problem could be solved more easily using linked lists, where size is handled dynamically.

Here is a solution that replaces negatives with zeros.

```
class PossitiveArray { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int[] numbers = {2,-1,5,-4,3};
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(getPositiveNumbers(numbers)));
    } 

   public static int[] getPositiveNumbers(int[] numbers) 
   { 
       int [] nums = new int[numbers.length];
       for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
       { 
         if(numbers[i] > 0) 
         { 
             nums[i] = numbers[i];
         }
         else
         {
             nums[i] = 0;
         }

       } 
       return nums;
    }
 }
```

Comment: 'public class PossitiveArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] numbers = {2,-1,5,-4,3};
     System.out.print(Arrays.toString(nums));

    }
    public static int[] getPositiveNumbers(int[] numbers)
    {
     int [] nums = new int[numbers.length];
        for (int n : numbers)
        {
            if(n>0)
            {
                 nums = numbers;
            }
        }

        return nums;

    }
}'

Comment: Sorry im tried to post that as code. Im not sure how to call the function though in the main.

Comment: `
class PossitiveArray { 
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
    int[] numbers = {2,-1,5,-4,3};
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(getPositiveNumbers(numbers)));
  } 
   
   public static int[] getPositiveNumbers(int[] numbers) 
   { 
     int [] nums = new int[numbers.length];
     for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
        if(numbers[i] > 0) 
        { 
          nums[i] = numbers[i];
        }
        else
        {
            nums[i] = 0;
        }
        
     } return nums;
   }
 }`